# Sizing content dynamically with jquery on device change orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I have two button that I would like to scale dynamically when the page loads in to fit the my header on a mobile website. Thats pretty straight forwaord.

```
var btn_h = $('#menu_btn').height();
    $('#menu_btn').width(btn_h+'px');
    $('#search_btn').width(btn_h+'px');
```

The problem here is when the user/I change the orientation of my testing device the content is scaled is still set to the width/height of the previous orientation.

```
function setHeader(){
    var btn_h = $('#menu_btn').height();
    $('#menu_btn').width(btn_h+'px');
    $('#search_btn').width(btn_h+'px');
    alert('height:'+btn_h+'  width:' + $('#menu_btn').height());
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    setHeader();
    $(window).bind('orientationchange', function() {
        setHeader();
    });
});
```

I left a little alert in there to help. When the device is portrait the width and height are 42px when the page is refreshed in landscape the height and width is 27px.
The problem is that when the device orientation is changed the content is not resized the sizes stay the same as the previous size.
Is this because the function is running before the device has finished rotating and if so is there a way of running the function to re scale the buttons when the orientation change is complete?

Comment: no just jquery css html and php

Comment: use `$(window).on("resize", function()`. `orientationchange` event in only available in jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Didn't think it mattered, the funtion does fire though, by adding a timer like below. I'm using jquery-1.6.4.min.js btw

Comment: *** Update *** tried jquery mobile, result is the same.

Comment: From the jQuery manual: "Code in a resize handler should never rely on the number of times the handler is called. Depending on implementation, resize events can be sent continuously as the resizing is in progress (the typical behavior in Internet Explorer and WebKit-based browsers such as Safari and Chrome), or only once at the end of the resize operation (the typical behavior in some other browsers such as Opera)." to @Omar - jquery has a shorthand for that = .resize() , both of you check https://api.jquery.com/resize/ for more info

Comment: @jave.web In jQM the situation is different than jQuery in terms of binding event. Read more about jQuery Mobile.

Comment: @Omar nice tip, but OP said in comment that he is using regular jQuery, but you are absolutely right, there is no .resize() method in the jQuery.mobile , **HOWEVER** - the jQuery manual note about resize event still applys since androids and apples have WebKit-based browsers too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not fully supported yet, but the future solution will definitely be an usage of the `window.orientation` object. Example:

```
var orientation = screen.mozOrientation;

if (orientation === "landscape-primary") {
  console.log("That looks good.");
} else if (orientation === "landscape-secondary") {
  console.log("Mmmh... the screen is upside down!");
} else if (orientation === "portrait-secondary") {
  console.log("Mmmh... you should rotate your device");
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.orientation (where I took my example) for more info.

To Whether it is called before or after can be simply found out by putting a

`setHeader(); setInterval(setHeader,5000);`

inside the bind - it will show your alert each 5 seconds with actual values.
So just close the alerts until the page is rotated - then check for the actual value.

**EDIT:** if the longtime-load would be your problem solution would be to pro-long the interval

```
var timer = 1000; 
function rotCheck(){ 
   /*check*/ 
   timer=timer+1000;
   setTimeout(rotCheck,timer); 
};
rotCheck();
```

would be triggered after 1second, then after 2s, 3s, 4s, 5s... **aproximately...**

Comment: Definitely being fired after, didn't think of setting a time delay. I'm testing over my android xperia phone which isn't too fast about 1 second would be fine for the timeout but do you think there some devices may need more time for this?

Comment: please **CHECK THE EDIT** - thanks ! :) Sorry I missed typed the setTimeout should be setInterval... Anyway ... Maybe some older samsungs which were pretty good at providing good javascript even in the before-android era.

Comment: its fine I used timeout, only fires once anyway. Perfect for the function I need